# WordNet: how to determine the top two most related synonymes

Tags: python, similarity, wordnet

Is there a quick way to determine the most related synonyms using WordNet synset?. Below are my attempts:
...worked for some but not for others. If the first synset contains only the original word, then you can't get more than one such as in the example using friend below.

```
>>> [synset.lemma_names for synset in wn.synsets('car')][0][:2]
['car', 'auto']

>>>[synset.lemma_names for synset in wn.synsets('friend')][0]
['friend']
```

Actual sysets for friend:

```
>>>[synset.lemma_names for synset in wn.synsets('friend')]
[['friend'], ['ally', 'friend'], ['acquaintance', 'friend'], ['supporter', 'protagonist', 'champion', 'admirer', 'booster', 'friend'], ['Friend', 'Quaker']]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wordnet maps and relates senses not words. So **looking for related synonyms might not be possible in WordNet**. Also you fall into the problem of words with multiple senses; without the context, the senses of any word is unclear:

```
>>> wn.synsets('car')
[Synset('car.n.01'), Synset('car.n.02'), Synset('car.n.03'), Synset('car.n.04'), Synset('cable_car.n.01')]
>>> wn.synsets('auto')
[Synset('car.n.01')]
>>> wn.synsets('friend')
[Synset('friend.n.01'), Synset('ally.n.02'), Synset('acquaintance.n.03'), Synset('supporter.n.01'), Synset('friend.n.05')]
```

And when you look into the different senses that each lemma_name contains, you get an recursive chain of lemmas of synsets of lemmas of synsets ...:

```
from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain(*[j.lemma_names() for j in wn.synsets('friend')]))set([u'acquaintance', u'champion', u'Quaker', u'protagonist', u'friend', u'admirer', u'Friend', u'supporter', u'ally', u'booster'])
>>> [wn.synsets(i) for i in set(chain(*[j.lemma_names() for j in wn.synsets('friend')]))]
[[Synset('acquaintance.n.01'), Synset('acquaintance.n.02'), Synset('acquaintance.n.03')], [Synset('champion.n.01'), Synset('champion.n.02'), Synset('supporter.n.01'), Synset('ace.n.03'), Synset('champion.v.01'), Synset('champion.s.01')], [Synset('friend.n.05'), Synset('quaker.n.02')], [Synset('supporter.n.01'), Synset('protagonist.n.02')], [Synset('friend.n.01'), Synset('ally.n.02'), Synset('acquaintance.n.03'), Synset('supporter.n.01'), Synset('friend.n.05')], [Synset('supporter.n.01'), Synset('admirer.n.02'), Synset('admirer.n.03')], [Synset('friend.n.01'), Synset('ally.n.02'), Synset('acquaintance.n.03'), Synset('supporter.n.01'), Synset('friend.n.05')], [Synset('supporter.n.01'), Synset('patron.n.03'), Synset('assistant.n.01'), Synset('garter.n.01'), Synset('athletic_supporter.n.01')], [Synset('ally.n.01'), Synset('ally.n.02'), Synset('ally.v.01')], [Synset('supporter.n.01'), Synset('promoter.n.01'), Synset('booster.n.03'), Synset('booster.n.04'), Synset('booster.n.05'), Synset('booster.n.06')]]
>>> [k.lemma_names() for k in chain(*[wn.synsets(i) for i in set(chain(*[j.lemma_names() for j in wn.synsets('friend')]))])]
[[u'acquaintance', u'familiarity', u'conversance', u'conversancy'], [u'acquaintance', u'acquaintanceship'], [u'acquaintance', u'friend'], [u'champion', u'champ', u'title-holder'], [u'champion', u'fighter', u'hero', u'paladin'], [u'supporter', u'protagonist', u'champion', u'admirer', u'booster', u'friend'], [u'ace', u'adept', u'champion', u'sensation', u'maven', u'mavin', u'virtuoso', u'genius', u'hotshot', u'star', u'superstar', u'whiz', u'whizz', u'wizard', u'wiz'], [u'champion', u'defend'], [u'champion', u'prizewinning'], [u'Friend', u'Quaker'], [u'quaker', u'trembler'], [u'supporter', u'protagonist', u'champion', u'admirer', u'booster', u'friend'], [u'protagonist', u'agonist'], [u'friend'], [u'ally', u'friend'], [u'acquaintance', u'friend'], [u'supporter', u'protagonist', u'champion', u'admirer', u'booster', u'friend'], [u'Friend', u'Quaker'], [u'supporter', u'protagonist', u'champion', u'admirer', u'booster', u'friend'], [u'admirer'], [u'admirer', u'adorer'], [u'friend'], [u'ally', u'friend'], [u'acquaintance', u'friend'], [u'supporter', u'protagonist', u'champion', u'admirer', u'booster', u'friend'], [u'Friend', u'Quaker'], [u'supporter', u'protagonist', u'champion', u'admirer', u'booster', u'friend'], [u'patron', u'sponsor', u'supporter'], [u'assistant', u'helper', u'help', u'supporter'], [u'garter', u'supporter'], [u'athletic_supporter', u'supporter', u'suspensor', u'jockstrap', u'jock'], [u'ally'], [u'ally', u'friend'], [u'ally'], [u'supporter', u'protagonist', u'champion', u'admirer', u'booster', u'friend'], [u'promoter', u'booster', u'plugger'], [u'booster', u'shoplifter', u'lifter'], [u'booster', u'booster_amplifier', u'booster_station', u'relay_link', u'relay_station', u'relay_transmitter'], [u'booster', u'booster_rocket', u'booster_unit', u'takeoff_booster', u'takeoff_rocket'], [u'booster', u'booster_dose', u'booster_shot', u'recall_dose']]
```

In short, looking for related synonyms might not be possible in WordNet, most probably you would have to look for other resources.